# sql prefix with numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my `select` I have multiple dates in one rows, divided by comma.

Main select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.IDVazniZaznam,
stuff(
(
    SELECT ','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,DatumCasZacatku, 22) FROM HVZHlavicka_Prestavka WHERE IDVazniZaznam = p.IDVazniZaznam FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') As DatumCasZacatku,

stuff(
(
    SELECT ','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,DatumCasUkonceni, 22) FROM HVZHlavicka_Prestavka WHERE IDVazniZaznam = p.IDVazniZaznam FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') AS DatumCasUkonceni
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IDVazniZaznam, DatumCasUkonceni, DatumCasZacatku FROM HVZHlavicka_Prestavka ) p
```

Like this:

```
12/04/19  7:45:00 AM,12/04/19  8:00:02 AM
```

What I need to do is something like that:

```
 1: 12/04/19  7:45:00 AM, 2: 12/04/19  8:00:02 AM
```

Im not sure if its called prefix, but I think it is. I do not want to put it manually, but I wanna generate it automatically. First date will be number 1, second date number 2 etc.
Its that even possible in `SQL`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Add info about DB. Thanks for info. ;)

Comment: show us your select query

Comment: Select the items in a subquery with `RANK` to get the sequence and them concatonate them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STRING_AGG()`, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ..)`, `STRING_SPLIT()` and `CONCAT()` functions together ( *`STRING_AGG()` works for SQL Server 2017+* ).

In the first step we're splitting the string by comma delimiters in the subquery, and then concatenating those substrings through use of `STRING_AGG()` :

```
DECLARE @DatumCasUkonceni NVARCHAR(1000) = '12/04/19  7:45:00 AM,12/04/19  8:00:02 AM';

SELECT STRING_AGG(q.str, ',' ) as "Result"
  FROM
  (
   SELECT CONCAT( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @DatumCasUkonceni), ' : ',
          value ) as str
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DatumCasUkonceni, ',')  
  ) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=476a669449be0becbaf8434445743f04)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic from the below code-

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX) = '12/04/19  7:45:00 AM,12/04/19  8:00:02 AM'
DECLARE @remaining_text VARCHAR(MAX) = @text

DECLARE @new_text VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @CommaIndex INT
DECLARE @Count INT = 1

SET @CommaIndex = CHARINDEX(',',@remaining_text,0)

IF @CommaIndex = 0
BEGIN
    SET @new_text = '1: ' + @text
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    WHILE @CommaIndex > 0
    BEGIN
       SET @new_text = @new_text+ ' '+CAST(@Count AS VARCHAR)+': ' + LEFT(@remaining_text,CHARINDEX(',',@remaining_text,0))
       SET @remaining_text = RIGHT(@remaining_text,LEN(@remaining_text)-CHARINDEX(',',@remaining_text,0))

       SET @CommaIndex = CHARINDEX(',',@remaining_text,0)
       SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
END


IF CHARINDEX(',',@text,0) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @new_text = @new_text + ' '+CAST(@Count AS VARCHAR)+': ' + @remaining_text
END

SELECT  @new_text,@remaining_text
```

Output is-

```
 1: 12/04/19  7:45:00 AM, 2: 12/04/19  8:00:02 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

If [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) is available to your version of MS Sql Server (2017+), then something like this should do the job.

```
SELECT IDVazniZaznam
, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(rn,': ',DtStrCasZacatku),', ') AS DatumCasZacatku
, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(rn,': ',DtStrUkonceni),', ') AS DatumCasUkonceni
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT IDVazniZaznam
  , CONVERT(VARCHAR,DatumCasZacatku, 22) AS DtStrCasZacatku
  , CONVERT(VARCHAR,DatumCasUkonceni,22) AS DtStrUkonceni
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDVazniZaznam ORDER BY DatumCasZacatku, DatumCasUkonceni) AS rn
  FROM HVZHlavicka_Prestavka
) q
GROUP BY IDVazniZaznam;
```

And this will also work in MS Sql Server 2012

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT IDVazniZaznam
  , DatumCasZacatku
  , DatumCasUkonceni
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDVazniZaznam ORDER BY DatumCasUkonceni, DatumCasZacatku) AS rn
  FROM HVZHlavicka_Prestavka
)
SELECT q.IDVazniZaznam
, STUFF(a1.DatumCasZacatku,1,2,'') AS DatumCasZacatku
, STUFF(a2.DatumCasUkonceni,1,2,'') AS DatumCasUkonceni
FROM 
(
  SELECT IDVazniZaznam
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY IDVazniZaznam
) AS q
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT CONCAT(', ',rn,': ', CONVERT(VARCHAR,DatumCasZacatku, 22))
  FROM CTE c
  WHERE c.IDVazniZaznam = q.IDVazniZaznam
  FOR XML PATH ('')
) a1(DatumCasZacatku)
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT CONCAT(', ',rn,': ', CONVERT(VARCHAR,DatumCasUkonceni,22))
  FROM CTE c
  WHERE c.IDVazniZaznam = q.IDVazniZaznam
  FOR XML PATH ('')
) a2(DatumCasUkonceni);
```

Test for both on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d90b05558c65e3863beb1f06c91c7b4f)*